# Operable default menu *and* custom 3 menu

Tags: menus

OK, this is a basic question...I'm upgrading a theme I built (from scratch) to support 3.0 menus (finally).

With the new wp_nav_menu tag, as expected, the tag's default container is added when a custom menu is assigned only. The added div prevents the custom menu from taking the css I previously created.

I need to be able to support both default and custom menu. Rather than bulking out my css with added selectors to support the new class, I'd like to null the container and container_class in the wp_nav_menu array and state the container in HTML around the tag.

Is there any reason I should not do this? Is there a more elegant way of supporting both default and custom menus?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2):

Use `'container' => false,` in your wp_nav_menu array

Comment: Ah, yes, false, not a null value. Turns out there was an extra div in the default format that was dropped with custom menus. I got the same basic hierarchy with container_class => 'menu'.